# Magento How to check from where my custom block called

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to know from where my custom block called dynamically when e-store run, suppose developer added custom block at footer than i want to know that he added this block at footer. suppose he added same block in header than i want to know that he added it in header. so how can i know about this in magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the block instance you can check the parent block like this:

```
$parent = $block->getParentBlock();
```

Keep in mind that it this can return null if there is no parent block.
Also, your block can be inside a block that's inside an other block that's inside the footer. and so on....you might need to do a while loop until you get the desired block.
Something like this:

```
$parent = $block->getParentBlock();
while(some condition here) {
    if ($parent) {
        $parent = $parent->getParentBlock();
    }
}
```

TO get the block name you need to do this `$block->getName()` or `$block->getNameInLayout()`.